# AJAX/CSS - css issue initially on select box after ajax call fills it

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have an ajax call that fills a selection box with options. Only issue is on the initial click of the box after the ajax call has completed the styling is messed up. It is either completely black, or goes up a few inches in the screen. After I click the selection box again, you can see all the options fine as well as the formatting is how it should be. This issue also ONLY happens in chrome...firefox and IE this issue does not happen.

```
select {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: 130px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

select:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  background-color: #444;
}
```

Here is a link to my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/bu15pyoa/) which can sort of show an example of what I am doing. Obviously it is not a working example because the ajax call executes a query. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS/HTML looks fine in your example. If the styling is messing up after the ajax call you may need to inspect the data that you are receiving onsuccess.
Try to do:

```
success: function(success) {
    console.log(success.d);
}
```

To see if there are any invalid or invisible characters messing up your HTML. Good luck!